# How to identify state transition probabilities after getting Markov Chain using markovchainFit in R?

Tags: r, markov-chains

I have a sequence of events:

```
library(markovchain)
sequence<-c("LHR - BA","BOS - BA","BOS - ZE","IAD - ZE","BOS - BA","LHR - BA",
            "LGW - BA","TPA - BA","TPA - BA","LGW - BA","LHR - BA","BOS - BA",
            "BOS - ZE","BOS - ZE","BOS - BA","LHR - BA","LHR - BA","BOS - BA",
            "BOS - ZE","BOS - ZE","BOS - DL","ATL - DL","LHR - BA","BRU - BA")
```

Using this sequence, I get a Markov chain using the following function:

```
sequenceMatr <- createSequenceMatrix(sequence, sanitize=FALSE)
mcFit        <- markovchainFit(data=sequence, method="mle")
```

Consider that the next state is `"LHR - BA"`; how then do I identify the probability distribution across states in the following format:

```
           "LHR - BA", "BOS - ZE", "IAD - ZE", "BOS - BA", "LHR - BA", "LGW - BA", "TPA - BA"
"LHR - BA"     0.1   ,     0.2   ,    0.2    ,     0.3   ,     0.1   ,     0.1   ,     0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I find your question a bit hard to understand, but here is my interpretation.

> Consider that the next state is `"LHR - BA"`; how then do I identify the probability distribution across states

So the way I read this, you know that at some time *t*+1 your system is in state `"LHR - BA"` and you want to know the distribution probability at time *t*. In other words, you want the conditional probability

```
P(S(t)=x | S(t+1)="LHR - BA")
```

According to [Bayes' law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) this probability is equal to

```
P(S(t)=x) * P(S(t+1)="LHR - BA" | S(t)=x) / P(S(t+1)="LHR - BA")
```

For this to work, you need some estimate of the unconditional distribution. For large *t* and a reasonable (don't know the correct term here) markov chain you can simply take the (hopefully unique) steady state here. With that interpretation you can translate the above formula into R in a pretty direct manner:

```r
mcEst <- mcFit$estimate
mcSteady <- steadyStates(mcEst)
sapply(states(mcEst), function(x) transitionProbability(mcEst, x, "LHR - BA")*mcSteady[1,x]/mcSteady[1,"LHR - BA"])
```

But perhaps you want to write this in a nicer way, and have rows for every possible `S(t+1)` not just `"LHR - BA"`. For that you'll have to deal with the transition matrix more directly, instead of calling `transitionProbability`, since that method doesn't work well vor vectorized arguments.

```r
tm <- mcEst@transitionMatrix
if (mcEst@byrow) tm <- t(tm)
res <- tm * t(outer(mcSteady[1,], mcSteady[1,], "/"))
```

The first two lines obtain the transition matrix and make sure that the row (first index) is the target state and the column (second index) is the source state. See `getMethods("transitionProbability")` for shipped functions which do this kind of thing. So at that point you have

```
tm[i,j] = P(S(t+1)=i | S(t)=j)
```

You then take the steady state, and do all possible combinations. You get

```
outer(mcSteady[1,], mcSteady[1,], "/")[i,j] = mcSteady[1,i]/mcSteady[1,j]
```

which is the wrong way round. So you transpose it and get

```
t(outer(mcSteady[1,], mcSteady[1,], "/"))[i,j] = mcSteady[1,j]/mcSteady[1,i]
```

which you multiply by `tm` to obtain the final result:

```
res[i,j] = P(S(t+1)=i | S(t)=j) * P(S(t)=j) / P(S(t+1)=i)
```

Each row of that resulting table will be one distribution for a given successor state. Including the one you asked for:

```
> res["LHR - BA",]
  ATL - DL   BOS - BA   BOS - DL   BOS - ZE   BRU - BA   IAD - ZE   LGW - BA 
0.23379630 0.37037037 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.02083333 0.00000000 0.20833333 
  LHR - BA   TPA - BA 
0.16666667 0.00000000
```